# Cannot get vba excel to create Outlook appointment in non default calendar

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have looked and tried various answers here and other sites, whilst the code below works - it just will not create the appointment in the "Winder_Related" calender.  This is the second i.e. "2" calender under the default "Calendar", I have tried using that reference as well.

Note I use a single Outlook .pst file with 3 email accounts, I have seen other solutions but they refer to using non default email addresses / accounts, .pst files.
I do not need a recipient email address for these appointments

I only have 3 calendars, the default folder and 2 sub folders
Calendar (default)
Trip Calendar
Winder_Related

Here is the current code, which works but still creates it in the default calendar

```
Sub Create_Appt_For_WinderJob()

     ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select

  'This is meant to use "Winder_Related" folder, the 2nd sub folder under the deafault Calendar
        'however it still goes to default calendar
        
        Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim nmsNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
        Dim fldCalendar As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim OutAppoint As Outlook.AppointmentItem
        Dim ItemsCal As Outlook.items

        Dim SC As Range


        Set OutApp = Outlook.Application
        Set nmsNameSpace = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            
            'this is supposed to work, but the default is still used
            Set fldCalendar = nmsNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Winder_Related")
        
            
            'This next line uses the correct folder ID but still the default is used
            'Set fldCalendar = nmsNameSpace.GetFolderFromID("00000000B119696562A6BB4588F5F089C4B07208625E5F00")
    
        
            Set OutAppoint = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    

            Set SC = ActiveCell

      '**have not included multiple lines of code after here as it just collects info from various cells on the current row
      'and then uses this to populate appointment fields - it works fine**
        
        
Chees Brian "Decoboy"``
```

Comment: Either `.Create` in the default calendar then `.Move` to  `fldCalendar` or `.Add` directly to `fldCalendar`.

Answer (score 0):

The [CreateItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitem) method creates and returns a new Microsoft Outlook item. The item created will be saved to the `Drafts` folder (for emails) or any default one in that case (calendar). In that case you need to calls the `Move` method explicitly if you want to get it saved to any other be default.

If you need to create a new item in a specific folder you need to use the `Add` method of the `Items` class instead:

```
Set OutApp = Outlook.Application
Set nmsNameSpace = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            
Set fldCalendar = nmsNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Winder_Related")
        
Set OutAppoint = fldCalendar.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
```

You may read more about that in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/)
- [How to create and show a new Outlook mail item programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/26/outlook-create-show-message-programmatically/)

Comment: Thank you Eugene, this single change did the trick. 
Works perfectly now.
This spreadsheet is getting a little unwieldly - I'm planning to use an Access db instead next year, but wanted to get my macros / code working in Excel first.